# Restore master database into newly named database with .bak file

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wrote a script to restore to a new database that already has populated tables (basically the master database contains the same tables as the school database but one table needs renaming as it was renamed incorrectly in master). The .bak file was from the master database, and i'm trying to restore it to the new database, however I'm getting an error.

```
(2 rows affected)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
master                                                                                                                           mastlog

(1 row affected)

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

(1 row affected)


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

(1 row affected)

Msg 3176, Level 16, State 1, Line 59
File '' is claimed by 'mastlog'(2) and 'master'(1). The WITH MOVE clause can be used to relocate one or more files.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 59
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

And this is the script:

```
use school;

DECLARE @TableSchema sys.sysname = N'dbo'
DECLARE @TableName sys.sysname = N'rights'
DECLARE @OldTableName sys.sysname = N'rigths'
DECLARE @OldTableWithSchema NVARCHAR(256) = QUOTENAME(@TableSchema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@OldTableName)
DECLARE @TableWithSchema NVARCHAR(256) = QUOTENAME(@TableSchema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
             WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @TableSchema
             AND  TABLE_NAME = @TableName))
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_rename @TableWithSchema, @OldTableName
END

DECLARE @Table TABLE ([LogicalName] varchar(128),[PhysicalName] varchar(128), [Type] varchar, [FileGroupName] varchar(128), [Size] varchar(128), 
            [MaxSize] varchar(128), [FileId]varchar(128), [CreateLSN]varchar(128), [DropLSN]varchar(128), [UniqueId]varchar(128), [ReadOnlyLSN]varchar(128), [ReadWriteLSN]varchar(128), 
            [BackupSizeInBytes]varchar(128), [SourceBlockSize]varchar(128), [FileGroupId]varchar(128), [LogGroupGUID]varchar(128), [DifferentialBaseLSN]varchar(128), [DifferentialBaseGUID]varchar(128), 
            [IsReadOnly]varchar(128), [IsPresent]varchar(128), [TDEThumbprint]varchar(128), [SnapshotUrl]varchar(128)
)

DECLARE @Path varchar(1000)='C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\SQL2008backup.bak'
DECLARE @LogicalNameData varchar(128),@LogicalNameLog varchar(128)
INSERT INTO @table
EXEC('
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
   FROM DISK=''' +@Path+ '''
   ')

   SET @LogicalNameData=(SELECT LogicalName FROM @Table WHERE Type='D')
   SET @LogicalNameLog=(SELECT LogicalName FROM @Table WHERE Type='L')

SELECT @LogicalNameData, @LogicalNameLog

use master;

declare @MasterData nvarchar(512)
exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer\Parameters', N'SqlArg0', @MasterData output
select @MasterData=substring(@MasterData, 3, 255)
select @MasterData=substring(@MasterData, 1, len(@MasterData) - charindex('\', reverse(@MasterData)))
print @MasterData

declare @MasterLog nvarchar(512)
exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer\Parameters', N'SqlArg2', @MasterLog output
select @MasterLog=substring(@MasterLog, 3, 255)
select @MasterLog=substring(@MasterLog, 1, len(@MasterLog) - charindex('\', reverse(@MasterLog)))
print @MasterLog

declare @NewDefaultData nvarchar(512)
select isnull(@NewDefaultData, CONVERT(nvarchar(512), @MasterData))
declare @NewDefaultLog nvarchar(512)
select isnull(@NewDefaultLog, CONVERT(nvarchar(512), @MasterLog)) 

SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY 10
ALTER DATABASE school
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

RESTORE DATABASE school FROM DISK=@Path
WITH
    MOVE @LogicalNameData TO @NewDefaultData,
    MOVE @LogicalNameLog TO @NewDefaultLog,
    REPLACE

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
             WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @TableSchema
             AND  TABLE_NAME = @OldTableName))
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_rename @OldTableWithSchema, @TableName
END
```

**Updated with new code but new error**

Answer (score 5):

The Master database is usually used for system tables and I have never seen it used for application tables. If by accident it was used you should restore the database under a different name and copy out the tables (and other user objects) to a user database. If you insist on using master (and as we say in Brooklyn only bad things can come from this) you need to do the following:

1. Put the database in single user mode (by using the `-m` parameter in the startup file)
2. From `sqlcmd` run this command (with the actual location of the backup file):

   ```
   RESTORE DATABASE master   
   FROM DISK = 'c:\backups\master.bak'    
   WITH REPLACE;
   ```

Comment: Have to agree; the real problem is the OP has user tables in the `master` database. Certainly they may have custom user functions (although even this is generally a bad idea unless you're making a system function), but certainly not data. Data belongs in a user database, and only in a user database.

Comment: Hey Ben, some plank used the master database sadly hence why we are moving to a user one...

Comment: Going forward we will be restoring from the school database but for old users, we are implementing a way to restore bak files from the master db (old versions of the software) to the new db (school)

Comment: Then do as suggested here and restore the "master" database as a different database, and then move the data to a proper, well maintained database, that is neither `master` or the restored "old" `master` database, @slickchick2

Comment: `master` can only be restored on am instance where the version **exactly** matches that of the instance it was backed up from as well; if the versions differ (backwards or forward) you cannot overwrite `master` with a backup (and if you did, you would break the instance).

Comment: yep that's what i was trying to do but i was getting the errors... because i wanted to restore into school

Comment: yep i'm restoring master into a new database hence why i know it would break if i tried to restore to master as i'm doing sql 2008 to 2016

Comment: @slickchick2 that is t how you do an upgrade

Answer (score 3):

You need to *overwrite* your current database with the backed up database. You can do this [with the `REPLACE` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

The basic syntax is...

```
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY 10
ALTER DATABASE master
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
restore database master from disk = 'c:\somefile.bak'
with replace
```

Comment: I did `RESTORE DATABASE school FROM DISK=@Path
WITH
 MOVE @LogicalNameData TO @NewDefaultData,
 MOVE @LogicalNameLog TO @NewDefaultLog,
 REPLACE` 

And i get an error saying Msg 3176, Level 16, State 1, Line 54
File '' is claimed by 'mastlog'(2) and 'master'(1). The WITH MOVE clause can be used to relocate one or more files.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 54
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: You need to be in [SINGLE USER mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-the-master-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). It's much easier in SQLCMD

Comment: Can i do this in SSMS?

Comment: `SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY 10
ALTER DATABASE school
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

RESTORE DATABASE school FROM DISK=@Path
WITH
 MOVE @LogicalNameData TO @NewDefaultData,
 MOVE @LogicalNameLog TO @NewDefaultLog,
 REPLACE`

Failed with error:

`File '' is claimed by 'mastlog'(2) and 'master'(1). The WITH MOVE clause can be used to relocate one or more files. `

Sorry being a noob